# What’s the word to describe a person in this role?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I was watching a prank, and I wonder what they call, or how you describe,
the person in the prank who is not a bystander but pretends to be one.  Is there a noun for this?

He is with the prank-makers and is assigned to purposely act as a bystander to fool other people.

Comment: By the way, "prank-makers" could be "pranksters".

Comment: That would be a "shill".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibilities include:

- a secret accomplice
- a secret confederate
- a secret co-conspirator
- a shill
- a plant
- a ringer

You could use *hidden* or *unknown* or some such in lieu of *secret*.  The entries without *secret* already contain that element built right into them.

Comment: +1 for the shotgun approach. You hit it with *shill*. As a side note, in grifter cant, the term for someone who brings in a mark to be cheated in a con game is called a *roper*.

Comment: @Robusto *Shill* was my first thought.  Thanks for Mr Roper — I didn’t know about him. ELU needs more cant.

Comment: I'm wondering if _decoy_ could be added to this list.

Comment: I'd say *shill* as well.

Comment: A decoy implies that they are a co-conspirator, but isn't the question asking more for a general co-conspirator rather than one with a specific role in the conspiracy?

Answer (score 11):

The first word that comes to mind for me is

> ["a **stooge** [in the audience]"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20stooge%20in%20the%20audience%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [*- any underling, assistant, or accomplice.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stooge)

There are [lots of alternatives](http://thesaurus.com/browse/shill). I've linked there to synonyms for **shill**, but I think that's more strongly associated with *fake **buyers*** (in an auction, for example), rather than accomplices in a prank.  The best of the rest is probably plain and simple **plant**.